# VBA to trigger Market Data Engine restart

Tags: vba, excel, reuters

I have PPP.xla, DDE.xla, PPPInit.xla Add-in installed. 
But I don't know the Protected Password for those Add-in. 
If I want to trigger [Market Data Engine Restart], which function i should call?

```
Call Application.Run("???")
```

The reason I want this is becoz sometimes when I use RtHistory("IDN", ,,,), it does not work (return "#N/A N/A") unless I restart PowerPlusPro.exe or when i clicked [Restart Data Engine] in the Reuters ToolBar. And I want to automate this RtHistory job by calling Excel using VBScript. Therefore I must have this function name to trigger the restart before fetching data.

Any experts have idea on this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by re activating the powerplus pro addin.

```
sub yourSub()
 Dim wbName As String

 wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
 Call activateAddIn("PowerPlus Pro Excel v5.1")
 Workbooks(wbName).Activate

end sub

'/**
' ReActivate AddIn
'**/
Public Function activateAddIn(AddinName As String) As Boolean
    AddIns(AddinName).Installed = False
    AddIns(AddinName).Installed = True
    Sleep 5000
End Function
```

cheers

stephan